# Publishing Story in Facebook using Open Graph with custom property of type Profile only works with user nameID not ID

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm publishing a story using the iOS facebook API.

The Story (Share a bracelet) contains two objects, the "bracelet" which is being shared and the "receiver" (profile type) which is receiving the bracelet.

Everything goes fine when posting, no error received and when i inspect the object or action using the Graph API Explorer i see the properties filled.

The problem: The story only shows the property of type Profile when is posted using the Facebook NameID and it is not showed when used the ID of the user.

This is my definition of the Attachment of the story:

[image: Attachment in the Story]

And this is my code to publish the action: (object is previously posted)

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/com_movetoshare:bracelet" graphObject:(NSDictionary <FBOpenGraphObject> *)@{@"object":shareDict} completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        // get the object ID for the Open Graph object that is now stored in the Object API
        NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
        DLog(@"FB : PostShare : object id: %@", objectId);

        //here we have an Object. Must create an Action with that object linked
        // create an Open Graph action
        NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphAction> *action = (NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphAction>*)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
        action[@"fb:explicitly_shared"] = @"true";
        action[@"message"] = status;
        action[@"bracelet"] = objectId;
        action[@"receiver"] = fbReceiverID;
        // create action referencing user owned object
        [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/com_movetoshare:share" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if(!error) {
                DLog(@"FB : PostShare : Action id: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]);
            } else {
                // An error occurred
                DLog(@"FB : PostShare : ERROR posting Action to Open Graph: %@", error);
            }
        }];

    } else {
        // An error occurred
        DLog(@"FB : PostShare : ERROR posting the Open Graph object to the Object API: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

When the variable fbReceiver ID contains for example @"facesmo.depruebas" (my test user) it works and shows this:

[image: Correct post]

but when the variable fbReceiver contains the user ID @"100002871792152" it publishes Ok but the profile data is not showedin the story. It shows:

[image: Incorrect Post]

The action has the property receiver defined as required so i can deduce that the data is correct.

Anyone knows why is it not showing when using ID instead of NameID?